# PDO - Count all queries in one reload the page

Tags: pdo, count

How I can count all queries in one reload the page in PDO? I must create own function or in PDO is support function to count queries?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do.  I don't understand

Comment: Sure.
`<php
// here page start
$sql = $db->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table order by id;");
// here next query
// here next query
// ...

echo 'You did XX queries to database.';

?>`

How I can count all queries?

Answer (score 0):

No, PDO don't support function to count queries. You have to create a function for this.